# Get tls keys from a powershell call

Tags: powershell, tls1.2

I was using wireshark to see some https packets when trying to access an website through any WebBrowser. Pretty much we just store the tls session keys in a env variable called SSLKEYLOGFILE to an txt file and then ask wireshark to use it in order to decrypt.

I also have a powershell script that uses some APIs from a website and I just would like to know if/how can I get the tls session keys to decrypt a https traffic that was generated by my Invoke-WebRequest call in powershell.

I have tried the same steps for browser tsl key tracking but no success. Just hoping if I can have the same but for when I execute a powershell call to an website

Thanks

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question; but it feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What do you need these keys for?

Comment: There are tools such as [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) for easy HTTPS debugging.

Comment: @JohnLBevan, the keys are needed to decrypt the https traffic recorded in wireshark. These keys are been stored correctly if I try to call any website using a webbrowser and I can decrypt the communication with wireshark using these keys.

If I attempt to use powershell to generate a https communication, I can't see the sessions keys been stored to use then in wireshark again.

Maybe I can change the question to: How do I decrypt wireshark https messages when using powershell calls (Since most of tutorials/guides only shows it through a web browser)

Comment: @vonPryz, I know Fiddler and it is a great tool. Just asking about wireshark since I can't install Fiddler on the machine

Comment: Ah understood - thanks.  This looks like it may be useful to you (if very complex): [5.4 Automation with frida-trace](https://b.poc.fun/decrypting-schannel-tls-part-1/).  Hope it's useful.  The summary & notes on how to use the script they created can be found here: https://github.com/ngo/win-frida-scripts/tree/master/lsasslkeylog-easy